# Question about Inventions and writing an episode (sequences)

Tags: theory, composition

I am writing the first part of an invention. I wrote it to the first cadence (C Major) but realized I did not create an episode with sequences. I am a little stuck on how I would go about doing that. Where should the sequences start? What exactly in my piece is the basis for my sequences? I appreciate any feedback.

This is what I have: [image]

Answer (score 1):

What is written so far is a single phrase comprising your subject, played in canon, and ending on a cadence in C. Start your sequence right there.

As an example, consider Bach's Invention #1:

[image: Bach Invention in C Major, mm. 1-5]

([IMAGE SOURCE](https://ks.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/5/53/IMSLP128949-WIMA.b5e1-Bach_Invention_01.pdf))

In measures 1 and 2 Bach lays out the primary theme, and cadences in C major on the downbeat of measure 3. He then immediately takes off on a sequence.

In your piece, there are frequent three-note scalar passages, and they would make an excellent basis for a sequence. For example, starting from where you've ended:

```
X: 1
T: Sequence example
M: 6/8
L: 1/8
K: F
%%score V1 | V2
[V:V1] c'ba b3/2c'/2b | agf g3/2f/2g | fed e3/2f/2e |
[V:V2 clef=bass] C3 G,3 | A,3 E,3 | F,3 C,3 |
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So, my sequence can start where I ended? I was thinking I need my first episode to be before I modulate to C Major. In other words, start my sequence and add b naturals maybe measure 5?

Comment: @DylanCataldo Measure 5 seems fine, but keep in mind you've already modulated to C at that point -- or at least, you've cadenced in C. If it's important to you to have the sequence first, then you'll need to rework your main motive so that it doesn't change key.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1MWpwBn would this be a good start to a sequence for measure 5? Or am I still cadencing to C already? When should I begin to use the b natural to signal the C cadence?

Comment: You're no longer cadencing in C; you've returned to F to begin the sequence. The sequence starts off fine, but I think you'll run into some trouble with it. Try F-E-F-D-E-F / G-F-G-E-F-G / etc. You should find the entry point for B natural comes more easily. Separately from this, just know that this conversation has really turned into a chat topic, so if you'd like to continue discussion, please post there. If you "@" me, I'll see it.

Comment: I would like to continue this discussion. I am stuck on moving forward with my invention. I have been reading about how to go about it but am still unsure. I have the first episode completed to the first cadence into C Major. But from there I am stuck

Comment: @DylanCataldo Got your message. We can continue the discussion here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room. You'll see I've posted an initial comment there.